# Correct return value with PInvoke char** (C -> C#)

Tags: c#, c, matlab, pinvoke

My problem is that I'm using the MATLAB API from C# and this is the function that is giving me trouble.

C code:

```
EXTERN_C char ** matGetDir(MATFile * pMF, int *num);
```

I expected this to work, but unfortunately it doesn't (C# code):

```
[DllImport("libmat.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern string[] matGetDir(IntPtr matFile, ref int num);
```

If I put `IntPtr` instead of `string[]` I can call the function, but then I don't know how to convert the code from `IntPtr` to `string[]`

Edit1:
I also tried using these attributes, but it fails with error: Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
private static extern string[] matGetDir(IntPtr matFile, ref int num);
```

Comment: Consider that 'char' in C is one byte, and 'char' in C# is two bytes.

Comment: Find more information here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17450/Marshal-an-Array-of-Zero-Terminated-Strings-or-Str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tell the p/invoke marshaller how to marshal this for you. You need to do it manually. One thing that is interesting about your question is that you don't give any details of what this `char**` really is. It's really important for you to learn that a type does not fully define the semantics of a parameter, or in this case a return value.

We can guess easily enough, but it is better to look this up in the documentation: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matgetdir.html

> ### Arguments
>
> #### mfp
>
> Pointer to MAT-file information
>
> #### num
>
> Pointer to the variable containing the number of mxArrays in the
>   MAT-file
>
> ### Returns
>
> Pointer to an internal array containing pointers to the names of the
>   mxArrays in the MAT-file pointed to by mfp. In C, each name is a
>   NULL-terminated string. The num output argument is the length of the
>   internal array (number of mxArrays in the MAT-file). If num is zero,
>   mfp contains no arrays.
>
> matGetDir returns NULL in C (0 in Fortran). If matGetDir fails, sets
>   num to a negative number.

So, we declare the p/invoke like this:

```
[DllImport("libmat.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr matGetDir(IntPtr matFile, out int num);
```

Call it like this:

```
int num;
IntPtr matFile = ...;
IntPtr namesPtr = matGetDir(mayFile, out num);
if (names == IntPtr.Zero)
    // handle error
string[] names = new string[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    int offset = i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
    names[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(namesPtr, offset));
}
```

Comment: @CitizenInsane Yes.  And the point about documentation and parameter semantics being important. As someone who answers a lot of interop questions, that's the biggest point to get across. `char**` can be many different things, so you always have to define the meaning.  I like your use of LINQ though. Quite cute.  I'll certainly make note of that!

Comment: I modified the code in my answer to handle for special cases + added call to `mxFree` *(matGetDir allocates memory for the internal array of strings using a mxCalloc. Free the memory using mxFree when you are finished with the array.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
[DllImport("libmx.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void mxFree(IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("libmat.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]        
private static extern IntPtr matGetDir(IntPtr matFile, ref int num);

public static string[] matGetDir(IntPtr matFile)
{
    // Obtain as IntPtr
    var count = 0;
    var pointers = matGetDir(matFile, ref count);

    // Handling errors as noticed by David Heffernan
    if (count < 0) { throw new Exception("Failed to obtain list of variables in selected mat file."); }
    if (pointers == IntPtr.Zero) { return new string[0]; }

    // Cast into IntPtr[]
    var ptrs = new IntPtr[count];
    Marshal.Copy(pointers, ptrs, 0, count);

    // Convert each value in IntPtr[] into string
    // NB: using System.Linq;
    var strs = ptrs.Select(x => Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(x)).ToArray();

    // Don't forget to free memory allocated by Matlab
    // NB: Deleting global pointer only ==> see "edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/eng_mat/matdgns.c']);" example 
    mxFree(pointers);

    // And voilà
    return strs;
}
```

So just making conversion into `IntPtr` in a private method as you initally tried and then adding a public method for conversion to `string[]`. See comments in the code for more details.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. But I chose the other one because it was better explained. But I will also use the mxFree which you mentioned.